# How to design the blade twist angle in propeller design?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, airfoil, blade

I am designing a scale propeller for small UAVs and I have computed blade twist distribution for the blade airfoil sections. While I was modelling the propeller I have set the angles to twist about the trailing edge of each section so that this point is collinear. However, the final result looks a bit weird. 
I would like to ask whether I have to consider any other point of the airfoil to set for the twist angle (Maybe leading edge or C.G). Below is a screenshot for the final model.

[image][image]

Comment: Static and dynamic aeroelastic properties will be important. Therefore a twist location at the quarter chord will (probably) work better.

Answer (score 2):

You should be twisting the profile chord, like in the picture. Why is your tip so small, that is where most thrust is created.

[image] [Source](http://www.pilotfriend.com/training/flight_training/fxd_wing/images/46.jpg)

Comment: That is what the optimization tool generated for chord and twist distribution. But i can trim some sections off i suppose.

Comment: @george: What tool did you use? I recommend [XROTOR](http://web.mit.edu/drela/Public/web/xrotor/) - that will give you a proper looking blade.

Comment: @PeterKämpf I have used Qmil which jhas similar documentation with XROTOR, so i don't think twist angles and chord lengths are the issues. It might be that i have to consider the twist angle from the center of mass of each airfoil section.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think performance will change, wether you use trailing edge or leading edge or somewhere in between reference for twisting. What matters is radial airfoil morphing along radius and common sense mass distribution around centripetal constraints. following those you wont come up with a straight twisting reference line. Have a look at [APC](https://www.apcprop.com/Articles.asp?ID=262#airfoil) model propellers site, it may help.